# Passing and retrieving Attributes using OneLogin java SAML authentication

Tags: java, saml, onelogin

I currently have a webapp working with OneLogin's java API https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/java . I need to let the person authenticating pass an attribute in when authenticating with SAML. I then need to retrieve that attribute using the auth object. There are examples of displaying the default attributes after authentication in the java sample project in acs.jsp, but how do I allow a user to pass a totally new attribute and retrieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I researched and it turns out you have to do this in the OneLogin Administration section. Go to Apps-> then click on Parameters add add a parameter. This apparently needs to be done to let the user pass in attributes that can be read with the Auth.getAttributes() method.